# How could i make this calculator in Elixir better?

Tags: elixir

*I am incredibly new to Elixir in terms of getting into learning it, i come from no programming background.*

Is there a better way i could write a function to do a calculator in Elixir? Also how do i call these individually from the command line without running elixir add.exs ?

```
defmodule Numbers do

  defmodule Addition do
    def add(a, b) do
      a + b
    end
  end

  defmodule Subtract do
    def sub(a, b) do
      a - b
    end
  end

  defmodule Divide do
    def div(a, b) do
      a / b
    end
  end

  defmodule Multiply do
    def mul(a, b) do
      a * b
    end
  end

end


IO.puts Numbers.Addition.add(1, 2)
IO.puts Numbers.Subtract.sub(1, 2)
IO.puts Numbers.Divide.div(1, 2)
IO.puts Numbers.Multiply.mul(1, 2)
```

OUTPUT

```
CPUs-MacBook-Air:lib cpu$ elixir add.exs
3
-1
0.5
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really have nested modules for such a simple application. A good thing to do before writing code is to think of the different things you will need and how they relate to each other. You have a module Numbers and you want to add, subtract, divide and multiply. These are operations done on numbers right? So provide them as public functions (operations after all) to your Numbers module.

.exs files are Elixir scripts. It means that when you load them, they will execute the functions you call inside the file (not the definitions, but the ones like IO.puts that you have there). If you want to interact manually with the module, then use a .ex file.

```
defmodule Numbers do

  def add(a, b) do
    a + b
  end

  def sub(a, b) do
    a - b
  end

  def div(a, b) do
    a / b
  end

  def mul(a, b) do
    a * b
  end
end
```

This can be your calculator program. Now you need to call it into the console (also called a REPL or Read Eval Print Loop).

```
iex c "numbers.ex"
```

and call the functions manually

```
alias Numbers, as: Calc
Calc.add(1, 2)
Calc.sub(6, 7)
Calc.mul(2, 4) |> Calc.add(6, 7)
```

And you may use it as you want. The alias word there means that you can create a "shortcut" for the module name, in this case I changed it to "Calc". Also useful if you got module's that are inside many directories like "ProjectName.SomeOtherName.YourModuleName" and then you alias that and can just use "YourModuleName" to call the functions.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot for taking the time. It's hard to find a lot about the language online, it's uphill but the community and this post (yourself) is very welcoming.

Comment: If you are a beginner I highly recommend the Slack community for Elixir. The people there are usually quite helpful, nice and welcome people who are new.

Comment: I will be sure to add myself into it. It would be so good to be able to learn it faster. My enthusiasm outruns my ability to learn the language almost daily. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Why do you need nested modules? You could put all these methods directly to `Numbers` module. And call them like `Numbers.add(1, 2)`
2. Run it as `iex add.exs` to be able to call these methods manually.
3. What kind of calculator do you want as result? Would you like to implement RPN or just get a result like `Code.eval_string("2+3*5") |> elem(0)`

Comment: 1. That's a good point that i didn't know. I didn't know about Modules i found out about it from reading here. (http://elixirschool.com/lessons/basics/composition/) 2. Is there any good guide on how to save and run these things within Elixir? 3. Just a very basic calculator that i can run from the command line.

Comment: 2. https://pragprog.com/book/elixir/programming-elixir is very good one.
You also could run `iex -h` to see all options. There is also some interesting info in the docs: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/iex/IEx.html
3. Could you provide some usage examples?